# non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame? How can I fix this?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, var, bandwidth

I am currently working on tv var applications for predictions. Unfortunately, I am an R semi-beginner.

My aim: I want to use the number of days since 2018-01-01 to select a good bandwidth parameter.

Somehow I get this error:

`**r in Math.data.frame(list(Days_of_observation = c(36, 37, 38, 39,  :  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Days_of_observation**`

This is the code and list I performed:

First the package and list:

```
install.packages("mgm")



df_list_copy <- structure(list(`Survey Creation Date` = c("2/6/2018 14:33", "2/6/2018 16:20", 
                                      "2/6/2018 18:54", "2/6/2018 20:08", "2/6/2018 22:29", "2/7/2018 8:43", 
                                      "2/7/2018 10:52", "2/7/2018 12:21", "2/7/2018 14:56", "2/7/2018 16:20", 
                                      "2/7/2018 18:27", "2/7/2018 20:11", "2/7/2018 22:15", "2/8/2018 8:34", 
                                      "2/8/2018 10:36", "2/8/2018 12:34", "2/8/2018 14:28", "2/8/2018 16:44", 
                                      "2/8/2018 18:41", "2/8/2018 20:24"), `Survey Completion Date` = c("2/6/2018 14:56", 
                                                                                                        "2/6/2018 16:22", "2/6/2018 18:58", "2/6/2018 20:22", "2/6/2018 22:46", 
                                                                                                        "2/7/2018 8:44", "2/7/2018 11:23", "2/7/2018 12:26", "2/7/2018 14:58", 
                                                                                                        "2/7/2018 16:21", "2/7/2018 19:55", "2/7/2018 20:13", "2/7/2018 22:16", 
                                                                                                        "2/8/2018 9:41", "2/8/2018 11:05", "2/8/2018 12:54", "2/8/2018 14:31", 
                                                                                                        NA, "2/8/2018 19:52", "2/8/2018 20:41"), `Since your last survey; how many alcoholic drinks have you had?` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, NA, 2, 5), `I feel comfortable in my current location` = c(88, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  81, 88, 89, 95, 94, 62, 82, 63, 80, 79, 81, 95, 100, 88, 83, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  50, NA, 72, 61), `I feel stressed` = c(10, 12, 69, 34, 16, 6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         27, 35, 56, 28, 58, 20, 32, 10, 26, 43, 44, NA, 57, 48), `I feel down/depressed` = c(14, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              18, 15, 18, 5, 2, 8, 4, 0, 11, 13, 10, 4, 6, 2, 7, 0, NA, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ))
```

This is the splitting of the time_date into dayno and beep (number of observations on one day)

```
## Create time date table with n of observations per day and days of observation since 2018-01-01

time_date <- df_list_copy %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(`Survey Creation Date`, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(Days_of_observation = Date - as.Date("2018-01-01"))


Beep <- time_date[2]
Dayno <- time_date[3]


bwSeq <- seq(0.01, 1, length = 10)
```

This is where I receive the error

```
set.seed(1)
bw_object <- bwSelect(data = df_list_copy,
                      type = rep("g", 12),
                      level = rep(1, 12),
                      bwSeq = bwSeq,
                      bwFolds = 1,
                      bwFoldsize = 10,
                      modeltype = "mvar",
                      lags = 1,
                      scale = TRUE,
                      beepvar = Beep,
                      dayvar = Dayno,
                      pbar = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues.

1. Argument *data* should be a n x p matrix object while you have used tibble object.
2. Given the matrix object in R contains only one type of data and the argument *data* should contain numeric data, I don't think you can directly use the time stamp together with the numeric object.
3. Argument *type* is a p vector(In your case, it should be a vector of length 6) while you have used a vector of length 12.
4. Argument *level* is a p length vector while you have used a vector of length 12.
5. From my debugging result, I think argument *beepvar* and *dayvar* should be a vector rather than a tibble.
6. From my debugging result, I think argument *data* should be a matrix that doesn't contain NA value in your case.

There may be some other issues. I strongly recommend you to understand the function `bwSelect()` first and check the demo code of `bwSelect()`.